# programmatically clone /etc/skel for new users

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, redhat, pam

`/etc/skel` is a folder that will be cloned for new users. Is there a possible way that we can define rules what to copy from `/etc/skel` folder?

For example, I'm looking for a way that if a user is created and belongs to group named `A`, clone `/etc/skel` folder except `/etc/skel/not_for_a.txt`. Possible?

Comment: [man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man5/adduser.conf.5.html) -- not a programming question; voting to close.

Comment: You can write a script that (a) creates user and then (b) performs whatever additional logic is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

`If  the  file  /usr/local/sbin/adduser.local exists, it will be exe‐
   cuted after the user account has been set up  in  order  to  do  any
   local setup.  The arguments passed to adduser.local are:
   username uid gid home-directory`

I can use `/usr/local/sbin/adduser.local` to call commands after user is created